# Clarification between MVC5 versus Core 1.0 and developing a web app using the Microsoft Stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, azure

I have experience developing in Visual Studio (and love it) and now wish to develop a new web application using Visual Studio and eventually (and hopefully easily) deploying to a Azure instance.

While I have experience developing simple applications in C#, this will be the first time I have ventured out of the standard HTML, CSS, JS that I have used before to make the simplest of web pages.

I have looked into Node.js and have seen Visual Studio (2013 I am using) support for it, but I have also discovered the MVC pattern (MVC5? Core 1.0?) in Visual Studio which in my amateur thoughts allows me to write my application logic in C# and use some special syntax in my html markup to reference what it seems like is variables or some dynamic content in my web pages.

The main thing for me is that this project is a LEARNING experience, and I want to develop this web application with in the most modern, scalable, and reliable way and for the first time develope a web application and deploy it to the cloud on my own domain.

So if I had to bottleneck a question here:

**What is the latest version/framework for developing web applications in Visual Studio such that they can easily be connected to TFS and later deployed to Azure?**

Really looking for resources here because I am having trouble understanding ASP.NET and the difference between MVC 5 and what I seen now is ASP.Net Core 1.0

Comment: There are a wealth of resources, including tutorials at http://asp.net  If you want to develop with the latest technologies, you should download the Visual Studio 2015 community edition (it's free).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image below will help with what ASP.NET Core 1.0 is. It runs on top of .NET Core 1.0 (look at icons which indicate cross platform support). So ASP.NET Core 1.0 is platform independent.

[image]

You can read more [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx). For practice purposes, create an MVC 5 app and deploy it to Azure. It can be done using Visual Studio and Visual Studio has support for TFS, GitHub and many other source controls.